# Taxonomy archive link from term id

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms

I'm using advanced custom fields taxonomy field to select a particular term of a custom taxonomy. I can generate the term ID based on the field but I can't display the link or the name of the term. Below is the code that I have that is generating a blank page

```
 <?php 
   $term_id = get_sub_field('expertise_category');
   $term_link = get_term_link( $term_id , 'expertise' );
   echo $term_link
 ?>
```

Comment: What have you done to debug? "Blank page" usually means *fatal error*. What PHP errors, if any, are being generated? What output do you get from `$term_id` and `$term_link` (e.g. via `var_dump()`)?

Comment: the content shows up till that point and then the page is blank. there are no errors as such. $term_id and $term_link both give the output I was expecting, an integer and a url. When put together I receive the error.

Comment: You'll need to enable debugging. (i.e. set `WP_DEBUG` to `true` in `wp-config.php`)

Comment: Looks OK for me. Are there any errors/warnings when you turn WP_DEBUG on?

Comment: No warnings with WP_debug. Where ever I place the code I get a blank page from that point on.

Comment: Are you using **Advanced Custom Field Repeater Field add on**? Because `get_sub_field()` is used with repeater field. If you're not using that add on, you must use `get_field()` instead and if you are using the add on you're missing some code. http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/functions/get_sub_field/

Comment: Wordpress Debuging Step 1) Deactivate Plugins, if plugins are the problem - reactive 1 by 1 to determine which one exactly.

Answer (score -1):

you need a semicolon at the end of your last line of code:

```
echo $term_link;
```